# MySQL Server Settings

Tags: mysql, macos, mysqladministrator

I have a mysql server that gets a lot of users logging in at once. I know in windows you can change the settings so the amount of people logging into the server will be okay on your traffic, but how can you do this on the mac?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`max_user_connections`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html). It defaults to 25 on installation.

Comment: An addendum: Don't forget to look at `max_connections` as well.